# Swiping between activities alternative?

Tags: android

Let's say I have a list of planets:
 1. Mercury
 2. Venus
 3. Earth
 4. Mars
 ....etc.

When the user clicks on Earth in the list, it launches the EarthActivity and from there on if the user swipes to the left, it launches the next activity (MarsActivity, in this case).

My question is should I be swiping between activities or is there a better way of doing this? And if there is, could you point me to a tutorial for it? Also let's say my list is larger, 99 items in the list. Would I have to create 99 activities and swipe between them?

I would like to have the swipe animation as well.

I am very new to android so sorry if I didn't explain the question too well.

Thank you.

Comment: You should make one generic Activity that loads data relating to the current planet, rather than having one Activity for each planet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a single activity and use the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with multiple fragments in it instead of multiple activities .

more info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) .

it has nice animations too!

btw, for some cool UI patterns , i suggest running this app that shows demos of open source projects :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns